# Import a module without its path in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a third party module named ng2-toastr, I moved it into one of my app folders and removed it from node modules and using npm uninstall ng2-toastr. Now I want to import it in my AppModule and other modules by its name (like I used to do when it was in node_modules) and not by its path, how can I do that?

Comment: Not 100% sure, so adding as a comment... In angular.json, there is a "scripts" property (projects > root > architect > build > scripts) property. I think you add the path to this. Please let me know if it's right.

Comment: Does not work that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to read this in detail http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Having said that, you can achieve this as noted on that document by adding a path to your tsconfig.json.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
    "paths": {
      "yourmodule": ["path/to/yourmodule"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

Note stuff inside node_modules has a default tree walk methodology to do what you intend, which is why it worked when you had that in node_modules (also explained in detail in that document).

Comment: It solves the issue and the application runs, however the IDE (WebStorm) still is unable to reference the library.

Comment: Ah, that may be a limitation on WebStorm, read this from their support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000390879-Error-Cannot-find-module-despite-module-installed-globally

Essentially, the module may need to be on the PATH. Hope that helps some, I do not really use WebStorm.